# Positioning tdclock in beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning, tdclock

I am just wondering how I can change the position of the timer in beamer. I was trying to locate the timer at the bottom left corner.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage[font=Times, timeinterval=1, timeduration=15]{tdclock}\setbeamertemplate{background}{\hspace{.5em}\textcolor{white}{\tiny\bfseries\crono}}


\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme[named=Cyan]{structure}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title[Title Short]{Title Long}
\author{Job}
\date{March 29, 2017}
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \initclock 
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using `background` template for that? Shouldn't you modify the footer?

Comment: That is how it was suggested by the authors of tdclock package (i.e., Luis Randez and Juan I. Montijano). I could, unfortunately, not find much help on other posts related to the tdclock package.

But the answer below by samcarter solves the problem. 

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick hack:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[font=Times, timeinterval=1, timeduration=15]{tdclock}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\rule{0em}{.99\paperheight}\hspace{.5em}{\color{white}\tiny\bfseries\crono}}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme[named=Cyan]{structure}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title[Title Short]{Title Long}
\author{Job}
\date{March 29, 2017}
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \initclock 
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sam, this is an excellent and very, very helpful answer! Thanks for your prompt and kind help.